# Class definition- two files

Tags: c++, class, char

I try to make class where I can creat new object of Student.
I've got some problem with definition of class body (student.cpp) and class (student.h).

```
Error:

In file included from student.cpp:1:
student.h:21:7: warning: no newline at end of file
student.cpp:6: error: prototype for `Student::Student()' does not match any in class `Student'
student.h:6: error: candidates are: Student::Student(const Student&)
student.h:8: error:                 Student::Student(char*, char*, char*, char*, int, int, bool)
```

**student.cpp**

```
 //body definition  
    #include "student.h"
    #include <iostream>

    Student::Student()
    {
    m_imie = "0";
    m_nazwisko = "0";
    m_pesel = "0";
    m_indeks = "0";
    m_wiek = 0;
    m_semestr = 0;
    m_plec = false;

}
```

**student.h**

```
//class definition without body

#include <string.h>

class Student {
    //konstruktor domyslny
    Student (char* imie, char* nazwisko, char* pesel, char* indeks, int wiek, int semestr, bool plec): 
    m_imie(imie), m_nazwisko(nazwisko), m_pesel(pesel), m_indeks(indeks), m_wiek(wiek), m_semestr(semestr), m_plec(plec)
    {}  
        private:
        char* m_imie;
        char* m_nazwisko;
        char* m_pesel;
        char* m_indeks;
        int m_wiek;
        int m_semestr;
        bool m_plec;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote a body for a Student constructor that doesn't take any parameters:

```
Student::Student( /* NO PARAMETERS */ )
```

But this function, `Student()`, is not in the class-definition.
This generates the error:

```
 prototype for `Student::Student()' does not match any in class `Student'
```

You need to write:

```
class Student {
    public:
        Student();  /* NOW it is declared as well as defined */
    [... all the other stuff ...]
};
```

Now, there is both a prototype for `Student()` and also for `Student(/* 7 parameters */)`

---

The fix for the other error is simple:

```
student.h:21:7: warning: no newline at end of file
```

The fix is to put a newline at the end of the file! :-)

Comment: You are missing that he has `{ }` in the header for the multiple parameter constructor. So that one *does* have a definition, while the no parameter one in the cpp does not have a matching declaration in the header file.

Comment: Now I understand my mistake. Everything works perfectly fine now.

Answer (score 2):

Your constructor in cpp file does not match constructor in header.
Every constructors/desctructors/methods realizations in cpp should be first defined in class in header.

If you want to have 2 constructors - 1 with no parameters and one with many parameters as you have. You need to add definition of your constructor in header.

```
//class definition without body

#include <string.h>

class Student {
    //konstruktor domyslny
    Student (char* imie, char* nazwisko, char* pesel, char* indeks, int wiek, int semestr, bool plec): 
    m_imie(imie), m_nazwisko(nazwisko), m_pesel(pesel), m_indeks(indeks), m_wiek(wiek), m_semestr(semestr), m_plec(plec)
    {}  //here really implementation made

    Student();  //one more constructor without impementation

        private:
        char* m_imie;
        char* m_nazwisko;
        char* m_pesel;
        char* m_indeks;
        int m_wiek;
        int m_semestr;
        bool m_plec;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In you header file you declare that `Student` has just one constructor with all the written parameters but no default `Student()` constructor, you should add it to header:

```
class Student {
  Student();
  Student(char* imie, char* nazwisko ... ) {}
};
```